# Passar props para componente neto react

Tags: react, propriedade, componentes

Tenho 3 componentes, Login, LoginPresentation e CpfPresentation. Login é o componente onde contenho toda a lógica e que chamam os respectivos "...Presentation", o Login e Cpf Presentation são onde está todo o código HTML, JSX na verdade.

Qual o problema ?

Tenho uma função "teste()" no componente Login e quero passar ele lá para o CpfPresentation, qual a estrutura??

Login chama LoginPresentation e LoginPresentation chama CpfPresentation. Então Login é avô do CpfPresentation. Então fiz assim:

```js
Login.js

export default class Login {
   teste() {
      console.log('Teste');
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <LoginPresentation 
               teste={this.teste}
            />
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

```js
LoginPresentation.jsx

export default function LoginPresentation(props) {
   return(
      <div>
         <CpfPresentation
            teste={props.teste}
         />
      </div>
   )
}
```

```js
CpfPresentation.jsx

export default funciton CpfPresentation(props) {
   return(
      <div>
         <button type="button" onClick={ () => props.teste() }>
            Executar
         </button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Mas clico e nada acontece, se eu crio o mesmo botão no LoginPresentation, funciona perfeitamente, alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: `this.teste.bind(this)` no componente `Login`.

Comment: Melhor maneira de compartilhar propriedades dessa maneira seria utilizando o hook "useContext" https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: A solução do `bind(this)` não funcionou. No LoginPresentation a função funciona, então o erro não é na hora de passar do Login.js para o LoginPresentation.jsx, e sim do LoginPresentation.jsx para o CpfPresentation.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não deve executá-lo no botão, pois função basea-se em referencia de memória, logo seu cpfPresentation deve estar da seguinte maneira:

```
CpfPresentation.jsx

export default funciton CpfPresentation(props) {
   return(
      <div>
         <button type="button" onClick={props.teste}>
            Executar
         </button>
      </div>
   )
}
```